# Do I have to send all trainging data columns when requesting a prediction from AWS SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm using the Javascript library @aws-sdk/client-sagemaker-runtime to interface with AWS SageMaker. I'm able to successfully request predictions from our model like this:

```
    const params = {
      EndpointName: this.endpointName,
      Body: csv,
      ContentType: 'text/csv',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    }

    const command = new InvokeEndpointCommand(params)
    const response = await this.client.send(command)
```

The `csv` here is a CSV string, without a header, containing one or more records to process, each containing the exact same fields in the training set, in the same order. If I remove any, I get an error.

This seems to be really inflexible -- this means that I need to keep track of the columns used in the training set, to ensure the data is sent in the correct order when requesting predictions (even the target column, and other columns I excluded when training).

Is there any alternative to this? It would be great if I could include a header (I tried this but it didn't work), or in some other way specify the data I'm supplying.